# rundeck - submit a job from the command line on linux?

Tags: rundeck

I have a scenario where I want to submit rundeck jobs via the cli just as if a person was sitting in front of a gui with a keyboard/mouse, to provide an additional way of convenience and automation.

Is there a cli tool for submitting rundeck (relevant doc link would be superb.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

U can refer this github :  https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck-cli

also u can build rundeck for your linux from source.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RD CLI](https://rundeck.github.io/rundeck-cli/commands/) tool.

Also, you can execute all Rundeck actions using the API, check [this](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/95797/rundeck/7TNfX9k?version=latest) and [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html#api-reference-version-34) to see the full API reference.